# Period of the decimal representation

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

Write a function which takes a single positive integer *n* and returns the period of the decimal representation of 1/*n*.

Test cases:

```
1 -> 1               # 1/1 = 1.0000...... = 1._0
2 -> 1               # 1/2 = 0.5000...... = 0.5_0
3 -> 1               # 1/3 = 0.3333...... = 0._3
7 -> 6               # 1/7 = 0.14285714.. = 0._142857
13 -> 6
14 -> 6
123 -> 5
345 -> 22
654 -> 108
12345 -> 822
67890 -> 120
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Built-ins or libraries which return the period directly are not permitted. Numbers up to at least 100000 should work within reasonable time (at most several minutes).

Comment: The question states that "numbers up to at least 100000 should work within reasonable time", but does the program have to give *the right answer* for numbers larger than this? Or would it be acceptable to use an algorithm that is only accurate up to 100000?

Comment: @FireFly Algorithms must provide the correct answer.

Comment: Why would 1 return 1? I would think 0?

Comment: @Timtech `1.00000000000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: @Cruncher Oh thanks, I get it now.

Comment: I think the output for `1` and `2` should be `0`, not `1`.

Comment: [A051626](https://oeis.org/A051626), but all 0s are replaced with 1s

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## APL, 19 chars/bytes*

```
{(↑⍳⍨1∘↓)⌽⍵|10x*⍳⍵}
```

[Nars2000](http://www.nars2000.org/). The previous version was wrong on some numbers, this should be right. I manually checked it on all numbers up to 50.

Again, credit goes to [Ben Reich](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11218/ben-reich) for the idea of looking at the period of `10^i (mod x)`

**Exploded view**

```
{                     ⍳⍵}   generate all naturals up to the argument ⍵
                 10x*       raise 10 to each of them, with unlimited precision
              ⍵|            compute the respective remainders mod ⍵
            ⌽               reverse the list
 (  ⍳⍨    )                 (fork) find the position of the first occurrence
  ↑                         of the fist element of the list
       1∘↓                  in the remainder of the list
```

**Examples**

```
      {(↑⍳⍨1∘↓)⌽⍵|10x*⍳⍵}¨1 2 3 7 13 14 123 345 654 12345 67890
1 1 1 6 6 6 5 22 108 822 120
```

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
<sup>*: APL can be written in its own (legacy) single-byte charset that maps APL symbols to the upper 128 byte values. Therefore, for the purpose of scoring, a program of N chars *that only uses ASCII characters and APL symbols* can be considered to be N bytes long.</sup>

Comment: I can't get the correct answer for e.g. input `20`. Can you please verify?

Comment: I followed the examples you posted. In your example, 1/2 = 0.5 -> 1, so naturally 1/20 = 0.05 -> 2. What are you getting?

Comment: The correct answer would be 1, since 1/20 = 0.05_0_.

Comment: I see. Give me a bit, I'll revise my answer.

Comment: `4` seems that it would give the wrong answer too, because `10 != 100 (mod 4)`.

Comment: Yes, apparently I had misunderstood the question, nonetheless I had come up with a formula that passed all the test cases! I'll revise my answer as soon as I can work on it.

Comment: @Tobia I assume that you have to remove all factors 2 and 5 from the input (as they are prime factors of the base).

Comment: Now it's ok. The previous version was computing the period only when there were no non-repeating decimals, otherwise it computed the number of non-repeating decimals (1/8 = 0.125_0_ would give 3) Don't ask me how I came up with that!

Comment: It wasn't even doing that. On `12` it would find two distinct remainders (`100 = 1000 = 4 (mod 12)`).

Answer (score 8):

### GolfScript (<strike>42</strike> 27)

```
{:x)1\[{.10*x%}*]-1%(?)}:P;
```

Benchmark time: 5 secs. Benchmarking code:

```
'"The time is #{Time.now#1
}"'~ puts
[1 2 3 7 13 14 123 345 654 12345 67890 99991]{[P]p}%
'"The time is #{Time.now#2
}"'~ puts
```

Credit to Ben Reich for the core idea of looking at the period of `10^i (mod x)`.

#### Explanation

The period `p` is defined as the smallest positive integer such that for all sufficiently large `i` we have `frac(10^i * 1/x) = frac(10^(i+p) * 1/x)`. We can simplify that slightly to `frac(10^i / x) = frac(10^(i+p) / x)`. Now, `frac(a / x) = frac(b / x)` iff `a == b (mod x)`, so we're looking for the smallest positive integer such that for all sufficiently large `i`: `10^i == 10^(i+p) (mod x)`.

Suppose `10^i == 10^(i+p) (mod x)`. Then `10^(i+1) == 10 * 10^i == 10 * 10^(i+p) == 10^(i+p+1) (mod x)`; so once we get a repetition, we're in an unbreakable cycle.

There are only `x` distinct values `(mod x)`, so by the pigeonhole principle we must get a repetition in the first `x + 1` values of `10^i (mod x)`.

So what the code above does is to compute `x + 2` values of `10^i (mod x)`*. Then the last one is guaranteed to be a repetition, and by reversing the list and searching for it I can find the most recent occurrence. Moreover, because I'm only doing the one search this is pseudolinear time.

* The extra one is to handle the special case `x = 1`, because I don't reduce `10^0 (mod x)` and so I'd be looking for a `0` in `[1]`.

Comment: Awesome! I've deleted my answer since a better solution! –

Answer (score 8):

### Golfscript - 26 bytes

```
{:i.)+.,{;10*i%.}%i>|,}:f;
```

*Edit: updated to output `1` if the decimal terminates, rather than the length of the decimal representation.*

A fairly efficient version. The value *67890* runs in approximately 10 seconds, and *99991* around 20 seconds. It's a bit slower than it was before (roughly half as fast), because the range that is iterated has been doubled, the first half of which is ignored.

**Alternative, also 26 bytes**

```
{:i.)+.n*{*i%.}%i>)^^,}:f;
```

This one works by iterating over the string `"\n"*(2*i+1)`, where `i` is the value passed to the function. The value passed to the block each time is the ordinal value of `"\n"`, which is *10*.

The `)^^` is a bit of a work-around. When you [uncons](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/builtin.html#%29) a character from a string, the result is the ordinal value of the character removed, as mentioned above. However, appending that value back on will append the *string representation* of that number, rather than the character - fairly nonsymmetric behavior, and in my opinion a design flaw. If you actually wanted to do that, stringifying first would only cost one byte.

An extra copy of the final value is already on the stack, so I remove the final value again `)`, xor it with the string, and then xor it again, so that any characters which were added or removed by the first xor are restored. If `int op string` were treated as a character, rather than its string representation, `)^^` could be replaced by `|`.

Note that while strings (which in Golfscript are stored as an array of ints) will display the value of each character mod *256*, the values of each character may themselves be outside this range. When testing for uniqueness (via set operations) or containedness (via `?`), it is the actual value that is compared, rather than the display value.

A patch file for the [current Golfscript interpreter](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/golfscript.rb):

```
61c61
<       to_gs
---
>       Gstring.new([self])
```

The above will only affect the behavior of `string op int` (and vice versa), where `op` is one of
`+-|&^`. Everything else remains unaffected, including the behavior of `` Gint` ``.

The following **24 byte** solution would then become valid:

```
{:i.)+.n*{*i%.}%i>|,}:f;
```

And this also fixes a lot of other [really ugly work-arounds](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8399/).

---

### Python - 48 bytes

```
f=lambda n:len(set(10**-~i%n for i in range(n)))
```

Not the most efficient solution, but reasonable for values less than *100000*.

FWIW, the core element is identical to my solution for [Generate cyclic numbers in decimal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12076/).

A more efficient version of the same code (**70 bytes**):

```
 def f(n):
  a=[];i=10%n
  while i not in a:a+=i,;i=i*10%n
  return len(a)
```

The value *99991* takes less than a second.

Comment: @PeterTaylor it `or`s the array onto an empty string. Because it's a set-wise operation, all duplicates are removed beforehand.

Comment: But where does the empty string come from? If the function is to be self-contained I think you're going to have to spend an extra byte and make it `.|`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor [fixed](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ezppKWksezsxMCppJS59JXwsfTpmOwp7OmkpLm4qeyppJS59JSleXix9Omc7CjsKWzEgMiAzIDcgMTMgMTQgMTIzIDM0NSA2NTQgMTIzNDVdCntmIHB9JQ%3D%3D).

Comment: Changing the behaviour of `string int +` would break a *lot* of programs. I'm not sure how often the other ops are used on that type pair.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I agree, it would. But consider: convert int to char: `[]+''+` vs `''+`. Append int, as char, to string: `[]++` vs `+`. Apend int, as string representation, to string: `+` vs `\`+`. In it's current implementation, `int''+` is synonymous to `int\``, which seems wasteful considering the verbosity of having to coerce to array, and then coerce to a string if you want the ascii char.

Comment: Also this version breaks on input `20`.

Comment: @Howard I agree. The correct answer [should be `0`](http://oeis.org/A051626).

Comment: @primo The correct answer [would be 1](http://oeis.org/A007732).

Comment: I understand that this is your expected output. But I also believe that it is categorically incorrect to say that the period length of 1/20 is 1. This would indicate that the value were 0.0(5...), which it isn't.

Comment: @primo Well, that's the way most people define it. And you may write `0.05(0)` instead which is clearly better ;-)

Comment: @Howard One may also write `0.05(00)`. _"This isn't the minimum period length!"_, you might say. One isn't either. The minimum period length is zero.

Comment: @primo I won't discuss this any further ;-) It is 1 by definition.

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript, <s>48</s> <s>47</s> 46

Thanks to @PeterTaylor for chopping two chars off.

```
{2{1$1$%!{.@\/\d}*}:d~;5d;9{2$%}{10*9+}/+,}:f;
```

I tried using J, but it kept giving me all sorts of strange results.

[Test online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=O3syezEkMSQlIXsuQFwvXGR9Kn06ZH47NWQ7OXsyJCV9ezEwKjkrfS8rLH06ZjsKWzEgMiAzIDcgMTMgMTQgMTIzIDM0NSA2NTQgMTIzNDUgNjc4OTBdCntmfSVw)

This basically divides 2 and 5 out of the number (2 and 5 are the prime factors of 10, and their reciprocals terminate, and stuff up the algorithm), then the lowest integer n such that the resulting number divides 10^n - 1 is the period.

Comment: If you know which will be the first call to your function then you can inline the definition there. I.e. instead of `{...}:d;...d` you save 1 char with `...{...}:d~`

Comment: @PeterTaylor thanks, hadn't thought of that

Comment: Having commented to Ben about not leaving `f` on the stack, I notice that you're doing it too. You should really add a `;` to pop the function for fair comparison with other languages.

Comment: Another micro-optimisation: `int array ,)\;` can be shortened to `int array +,`.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 52 characters

```
sub f{($p,%r)=1;1until$r{$p=$p*10%$_[0]}++;~~keys%r}
```

This is an uncomplicated implementation of the direct approach. (Fortunately the direct approach is also pretty efficient: thanks to modulo arithmetic, the math never has to deal with a number more than 10 times the input value.)

Since the challenge specified a function, I felt compelled to (re-)initialize my variables, something I wouldn't bother doing for a complete program. Likewise, the `~~` in the final statement is unnecessary if the function can be certain it will be invoked in a scalar context.

Comment: Try on input `20` where it yields the wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, <del>102, 117, 115</del>, 106

unformated:

```
(defn r([n](r{}(iterate #(mod(* % 10)n)10)0))([a[f & s]i](if(a f)(- i(a f))(recur(assoc a f i)s(inc i)))))
```

formatted:

```
(defn r
  ([n] (r {} (iterate #(mod (* % 10) n) 10) 0))
  ([a [f & s] i]
    (if (a f)
      (- i (a f))
      (recur
        (assoc a f i)
        s
        (inc i)))))
```

Running time scales with the period.  Almost instantaneous on my computer for the sample values.

Basically, this calculates the result of the subtraction after each step in long division.  A cycle is detected if at any point that number is the same as one that has been calculated before it.

Comment: The code breaks with input `20`. Can you please verify?

Comment: You are right,  the above solution is faulty.  Gonna see if I can fix it.

Comment: What is the expected output for 20?

Comment: The correct answer would be 1.

Comment: Should be good to go, first algorithm would fail on lots of inputs, for example 12 and 20.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
fq.^;yTQ.^;TQ
```

Uses [turtle-and-hare algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) ([more information](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Floyds-cycle-finding-algorithm-work)).

[Watch it pass every test.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fq.%5E%3ByTQ.%5E%3BTQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A7%0A13%0A14%0A123%0A345%0A654%0A12345%0A67890+&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÌLR°I%ćk>
```

Port of [*@PeterTaylor* GolfScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18550/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cI9P0KENnqpH2rPt/v83NjEFAA) or [verify almost all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/wz0@QYc2VKoeac@2@6/zP9pQx0jHWMdcx9BYx9BEx9DIWMfYxFTHzBTMNjGNBQA). The last test case is omitted, which takes little over a minute.

If we want to output all test cases in less than a second, a port of [*@primo*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19682/52210) could be used, which comes in at **14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** with a minor alternative of the same approach using a cumulative right-reduce:

```
>LTªÅ«T*I%}ćk>
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fzifk0KrDrYdWh2h5qtYeac@2@//fzNzC0gAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWhlf/tfEIOrTrcemh1iNahdaq1R9qz7f7r/I821DHSMdYx1zE01jE00TE0MtYxNjHVMTMFs0EscwtLAx1LIDCMBQA).

**Explanation:**

Based on the input \$n\$, I first generate a list within the range \$[n+1,1]\$. And then find the first 1-based index of a value \$x\$ which is truthy for \$10^x\pmod n=10^{n+2}\pmod n\$.

```python
Ì          # Increase the (implicit) input-integer by 2
 L         # Pop and push a list in the range [1,input+2]
  R        # Reverse it to the range [input+2,1]
   °       # Map each value to 10 to the power that value
    I%     # Modulo the input
      ć    # Extract head; pop and push remainder-list and first item separately
       k   # Get the 0-based index of this 10**(input+2) in the list of
           # [10**(input+1),10**input,...,100,10]
        >  # Increase this by 1 to make it a 1-based index
           # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
>L         # Push a list in the range [1,input+1]
  Tª       # Append a trailing 10
    Å«     # Cumulative right-reduce, keeping all intermediate results:
      T*   #  Multiply the current integer by 10
        I% #  Modulo the input
     }     # After the right-reduce:
      ćk>  # Get the 1-based index of the extracted head, similar as above
           # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 8 bytes

```
⇧ɾṘ↵%ḣḟ›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiIiwi4oenyb7huZjihrUl4bij4bif4oC6IiwiIiwiMzQ1Il0=)

Port of 05AB1E.

### How?

```
⇧ɾṘ↵%ḣḟ›
⇧ɾ        # Push range [1, (implicit) input + 2]
  Ṙ       # Reverse to make it range [input + 2, 1]
   ↵      # Map each value to 10 to the power of it
    %     # Modulo by the (implicit) input
     ḣ    # Head extract, push a[0] and a[1:]
      ḟ   # Get the index of this a[0] in this a[1:]
       ›  # Increment to make this a one-based index
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 33 bytes

```
n->znorder(Mod(10,n/gcd(n,10^n)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWNxXzdO2q8vKLUlKLNHzzUzQMDXTy9NOTUzTydAwN4vI0NTWhCoMTCwpyKjUSFXTtFAqKMvNKgEwlEEdJIU0jUVNTRyHaUEfBSEfBWEfBXEfBEEgZmgCxEZBhbGKqo2BmCuGC2eYWlgaxUKMXLIDQAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
üpßN▲╞§
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8170e14e1ec615&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A7%0A13%0A14%0A123%0A345%0A654%0A12345%0A67890&a=1&m=2)

**Approach:**

1. Multiply by 10
2. Keep only fractional part
3. Repeat until a loop of values is found
4. Keep only the loop
5. Get the length