# Find the repetend of the decimal representation!

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, number-theory

In [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18541/period-of-the-decimal-representation) 2 years ago, we found the **period** of a unit fraction (`1/n where n is a natural number`).

Now, your task is to write a program/function to find the **repetend** of a unit fraction.

The **repetend** is the part of the decimal expansion which repeats infinitely, like:

- The decimal representation of `1/6` is `0.16666...`, then the **repetend** is `6`.
- The decimal representation of `1/11` is `0.090909...`, then the repetend is `09`.
- The decimal representation of `1/28` is `0.0357142857142857142857...`, then the repetend is `571428`.

### Specs

- Input in any reasonable format.
- Output the repetend in decimal, **string or list**.
- For `1/7` (`0.142857142857...`), you must output `142857` instead of `428571`.
- For `1/13` (`0.076923076923076923...`), you must output `076923` instead of `76923`.
- No brute force, please.

### Testcases

```
Input    Output
1        0
2        0
3        3
7        142857
13       076923
17       0588235294117647
28       571428
70       142857
98       102040816326530612244897959183673469387755
9899     000101020305081321345590463683200323264976260228305889483786241034447924032730578846348115971310233356904737852308313971108192746742095161127386604707546216789574704515607637135064147893726639054449944438832205273259925244974239822204263056874431760783917567431053641781998181634508536215779371653702394181230427315890493989291847661379937367410849580765733912516415799575714718658450348520052530558642287099707041115264168097787655318719062531568845337912920497019901
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution in bytes win.

No answer would be accepted, because the goal is not to find the language capable of producing the shortest solution, but the shortest solution in each language.

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=78850,OVERRIDE_USER=42854;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39081/discussion-between-es-i-and-kenny-lau).

Comment: How do you decide that the repetend for 13 is 076923 and not 769230?

Comment: @aditsu Because `1/13` is `0.076923076923...` not `0.769230769230...`

Comment: Is it okay if the output is supposed to be `0`, a blank line is instead returned?

Comment: That didn't really answer my question, but I get it: you want the earliest repeating pattern, even if it starts with zero(s). Can you double-check your repetend for 98? Doesn't it start with 10204…?

Comment: Openly stating that you will never accept an answer pretty much makes this a catalog. Just don't say anything and never accept an answer.

Comment: How is the repetend of 1/17 `52941183`? To me it seems like there are no repeating sequences in its decimal representation...

Comment: @R.Kap The repetend is `0588235294117647`.

Comment: You could add a stack snippet to show the shortest solution for each language.

Answer (score 5):

## Java, 150 bytes:

```java
String p(int n){int a=1,p;String r="";for(;n%10<1;n/=10);for(;n%2<1;n/=2)a*=5;for(;n%5<1;n/=5)a*=2;for(p=a%=n;;){p*=10;r+=p/n;if(a==(p%=n))return r;}}
```

#### Added whitespace:

```java
String p(int n){
    int a=1,p;
    String r="";
    for(;n%10<1;n/=10);
    for(;n%2<1;n/=2)
        a*=5;
    for(;n%5<1;n/=5)
        a*=2;
    for(p=a%=n;;){
        p*=10;
        r+=p/n;
        if(a==(p%=n))
            return r;
    }
}
```

#### Ungolfed, full program:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A036275 {
    public static String period(int a,int n){
        if(n%10==0) return period(a,n/10);
        if(n%2==0) return period(a*5,n/2);
        if(n%5==0) return period(a*2,n/5);
        a %= n;
        int pow = a;
        String period = "";
        while(true){
            pow *= 10;
            period += pow/n;
            pow %= n;
            if(pow == a){
                return period;
            }
        }
    }
    public static String period(int n){
        return period(1,n);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        System.out.println(period(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(;;)` would be less bytes than `while(2<3)` though while also being an infinite loop! (and less bytes than `while(1)` also @Maltysen)

Comment: @Marv How could I have forgot that? Thanks!

Comment: Put the declarations for `a` and `r` in the for loops. Saves bytes!

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy It would make them inaccessible...

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 26

```
riL{_XW$%A*:X|X@-}g_X#>\f/
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=riL%7B_XW%24%25A*%3AX%7CX%40-%7Dg_X%23%3E%5Cf%2F&input=17)

**Explanation:**

The program builds a series of dividends involved in the calculation of the decimal expansion, until it finds a dividend it has seen before. Then it takes all the dividends starting with that one, and divides them by n to get the digits of the repetend.

```
ri       read the input and convert to integer (n)
L        push an empty array (will add the dividends to it)
{…}g     do … while
  _      copy the current array of dividends
  X      push the latest dividend (initially 1 by default)
  W$     copy n from the bottom of the stack
  %A*    calculate X mod n and multiply by 10
  :X     store in X (this is the next dividend)
  |      perform set union with the array of dividends
  X@     push X and bring the old array to the top
  -      set difference; it is empty iff the old array already contained X
          this becomes the do-while loop condition
_X#      duplicate the array of dividends and find the position of X
>        take all dividends from that position
\f/      swap the array with n and divide all dividends by n
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.5, <s>79</s> <s>74</s> <s>73</s> 70 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,t=1,q=[],*d:q[(*d,t).index(t):]or f(n,t%n*10,q+[t//n],*d,t)
```

*Saved 3 bytes by keeping track of dividends, an idea I took from [@aditsu's CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78871).*

Test it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/CLdV/5).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
%³×⁵
1ÇÐḶ:
```

*Saved 2 bytes by keeping track of dividends, an idea I took from [@aditsu's CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78871).*

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=JcKzw5figbUKMcOHw5DhuLY6&input=&args=OTg5OQ)

#### How it works

```
%³×⁵     Helper link. Argument: d (dividend)

%³       Yield the remainder of the division of d by n.
  ×⁵     Multiply by 10.


1ÇÐḶ:    Main link. Argument: n

1        Yield 1 (initial dividend).
 ÇÐḶ     Apply the helper link until its results are no longer unique.
         Yield the loop, i.e., everything from the first repeated result
         up to and including the last unique one.
    :    Divide each dividend by n.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 37 bytes

```perl6
{(1.FatRat/$_).base-repeating[1]||~0}
~0 max (1.FatRat/*).base-repeating[1]
```

If you don't care that it will only work with denominators that fit into a 64 bit integer you can remove the method call to `.FatRat`.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
# return ｢"0"｣ if ｢.base-repeating｣ would return ｢""｣
~0

# ｢&infix<max>｣ returns the numerically largest value
# or it's first value if they are numerically equal
max

(
  # turn 1 into a FatRat so it will work
  # with denominators of arbitrary size
  1.FatRat

  # divided by
  /

  # the input
  *

# get the second value from calling the
# method ｢.base-repeating｣
).base-repeating[1]
```

#### Test:

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;
use Test;

my &code = ~0 max (1.FatRat/*).base-repeating[1];
# stupid highlighter */
# Perl has never had // or /* */ comments

my @tests = (
  1    => '0',
  2    => '0',
  3    => '3',
  6    => '6',
  7    => '142857',
  11   => '09',
  13   => '076923',
  17   => '0588235294117647',
  28   => '571428',
  70   => '142857',
  98   => '102040816326530612244897959183673469387755',
  9899 => '000101020305081321345590463683200323264976260228305889483786241034447924032730578846348115971310233356904737852308313971108192746742095161127386604707546216789574704515607637135064147893726639054449944438832205273259925244974239822204263056874431760783917567431053641781998181634508536215779371653702394181230427315890493989291847661379937367410849580765733912516415799575714718658450348520052530558642287099707041115264168097787655318719062531568845337912920497019901',
);

plan +@tests;

for @tests -> $_ ( :key($input), :value($expected) ) {
  is code($input), $expected, "1/$input";
}
```

```perl6
1..12
ok 1 - 1/1
ok 2 - 1/2
ok 3 - 1/3
ok 4 - 1/6
ok 5 - 1/7
ok 6 - 1/11
ok 7 - 1/13
ok 8 - 1/17
ok 9 - 1/28
ok 10 - 1/70
ok 11 - 1/98
ok 12 - 1/9899
```

Answer (score 1):

## GameMaker Language, 152 bytes

*Based on Kenny's answer*

```
n=argument0;a=1r=0while(n mod 2<1){a*=5n/=2}while(n mod 5<1){a*=2n/=5}a=a mod n;p=a;while(1){p*=10r=r*10+p/n;r=r mod $5f5e107;p=p mod n;if(a=p)return r}
```

Comment: I just found a bug in my approach and fixed it, so maybe you would need to update this as well.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 122

```java
String f(int n){String r="";int x=1,a[]=new
int[n*10];while(a[x]++<1)x=x%n*10;do{r+=x/n;x=x%n*10;}while(a[x]<2);return r;}
```

Similar to my CJam solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 63 bytes

```
W!%QT=/QT;J*F+1-PQ,2 5K%*F+1-L7@,2 5PQJ=NKW1=+k/=*NTJIqK=%NJB;k
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=W!%25QT%3D%2FQT%3BJ*F%2B1-PQ%2C2+5K%25*F%2B1-L7%40%2C2+5PQJ%3DNKW1%3D%2Bk%2F%3D*NTJIqK%3D%25NJB%3Bk&input=70&debug=0)

Direct translation of the [answer in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78851/48934).

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 169 Bytes

```
$d=$argv[2];$a[]=$n=$argv[1];while($n%$d&&!$t){$n*=10;$r[]=$n/$d^0;$t=in_array($n%=$d,$a);$a[]=$n;}if($t)echo join(array_slice($r,array_search(end($a),$a),count($a)-1));
```