# Terminating, Purely Periodic, or Eventually Periodic?

Tags: code-golf, math, number

### Introduction

A decimal is terminating if it has a finite number of decimal digits. For example, 0.4 (2/5) is terminating because it has one decimal digit.

A decimal is purely periodic if it has an infinite number of decimal digits and has no decimal digits before its repetent (the part of the decimal that repeats.) For example, 0.142857142857142… (1/7) is purely periodic because it has a repetend 142857, which starts repeating immediately after the decimal point.

A decimal is eventually periodic if it has an infinite number of decimal digits and has a finite number of decimal digits before its repetent (the part of the decimal that repeats.) For example, 0.166666666666666… (1/6) is eventually periodic because its repetend 6 starts repeating after a 1.

### Your task

Write a program or function that, when given numbers *p* and *q* (integers, 0 <= *p* < *q* <= 100), will determine if the decimal representation of *p*/*q* is terminating, purely periodic, or eventually periodic.

You must output `a` if it's Terminating (i.e. 0.1), `b` if it's Purely Periodic (i.e. 0.333...), or `c` if it's Eventually Periodic (i.e. 0.166...), where `a`, `b`, and `c` are any distinct, constant strings of your choice.

### Test cases

```
0/1 => Terminating
0/2 => Terminating
1/2 => Terminating
0/3 => Terminating
1/3 => Purely Periodic
2/3 => Purely Periodic
0/4 => Terminating
1/4 => Terminating
2/4 => Terminating
3/4 => Terminating
0/5 => Terminating
1/5 => Terminating
2/5 => Terminating
3/5 => Terminating
4/5 => Terminating
0/6 => Terminating
1/6 => Eventually Periodic
2/6 => Purely Periodic
3/6 => Terminating
4/6 => Purely Periodic
5/6 => Eventually Periodic
0/7 => Terminating
1/7 => Purely Periodic
2/7 => Purely Periodic
3/7 => Purely Periodic
4/7 => Purely Periodic
5/7 => Purely Periodic
6/7 => Purely Periodic
0/8 => Terminating
1/8 => Terminating
2/8 => Terminating
3/8 => Terminating
4/8 => Terminating
5/8 => Terminating
6/8 => Terminating
7/8 => Terminating
0/9 => Terminating
1/9 => Purely Periodic
2/9 => Purely Periodic
3/9 => Purely Periodic
4/9 => Purely Periodic
5/9 => Purely Periodic
6/9 => Purely Periodic
7/9 => Purely Periodic
8/9 => Purely Periodic
0/10 => Terminating
1/10 => Terminating
2/10 => Terminating
3/10 => Terminating
4/10 => Terminating
5/10 => Terminating
6/10 => Terminating
7/10 => Terminating
8/10 => Terminating
9/10 => Terminating
0/11 => Terminating
1/11 => Purely Periodic
2/11 => Purely Periodic
3/11 => Purely Periodic
4/11 => Purely Periodic
5/11 => Purely Periodic
6/11 => Purely Periodic
7/11 => Purely Periodic
8/11 => Purely Periodic
9/11 => Purely Periodic
10/11 => Purely Periodic
0/12 => Terminating
1/12 => Eventually Periodic
2/12 => Eventually Periodic
3/12 => Terminating
4/12 => Purely Periodic
5/12 => Eventually Periodic
6/12 => Terminating
7/12 => Eventually Periodic
8/12 => Purely Periodic
9/12 => Terminating
10/12 => Eventually Periodic
11/12 => Eventually Periodic
0/13 => Terminating
1/13 => Purely Periodic
2/13 => Purely Periodic
3/13 => Purely Periodic
4/13 => Purely Periodic
5/13 => Purely Periodic
6/13 => Purely Periodic
7/13 => Purely Periodic
8/13 => Purely Periodic
9/13 => Purely Periodic
10/13 => Purely Periodic
11/13 => Purely Periodic
12/13 => Purely Periodic
0/14 => Terminating
1/14 => Eventually Periodic
2/14 => Purely Periodic
3/14 => Eventually Periodic
4/14 => Purely Periodic
5/14 => Eventually Periodic
6/14 => Purely Periodic
7/14 => Terminating
8/14 => Purely Periodic
9/14 => Eventually Periodic
10/14 => Purely Periodic
11/14 => Eventually Periodic
12/14 => Purely Periodic
13/14 => Eventually Periodic
0/15 => Terminating
1/15 => Eventually Periodic
2/15 => Eventually Periodic
3/15 => Terminating
4/15 => Eventually Periodic
5/15 => Purely Periodic
6/15 => Terminating
7/15 => Eventually Periodic
8/15 => Eventually Periodic
9/15 => Terminating
10/15 => Purely Periodic
11/15 => Eventually Periodic
12/15 => Terminating
13/15 => Eventually Periodic
14/15 => Eventually Periodic
```

<sub>You can find all test cases [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/We01u4eF).</sub>

You are allowed to choose your own 3 values for the output, but it must be clear as to which one it is.

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

### Hints

Terminating:

> The prime factorization of a terminating decimal's denominator in simplest form consists only of 2s and 5s.

Purely Periodic:

> The prime factorization of a purely periodic decimal's denominator in simplest form does not include any 2s or 5s.

Eventually Periodic:

> The prime factorization of an eventually periodic decimal's denominator in simplest form includes at least one 2 or 5, but also includes other numbers.

### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=95926,OVERRIDE_USER=12537;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: @ETHproductions Updated.

Comment: [Almost duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78850/194)

Comment: If I thought it was *actually* a duplicate, I would have cast a close vote. There's a reason that I used the word "*almost*".

Comment: *given a fraction in the form p/q* Given how? Can we take numerator and denominator as separate function arguments?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, they are separate function arguments

Comment: Can we output a non-constant value meeting a specific condition, such as anything falsy for terminating, 1 for purely periodic, and anything greater than 1 for eventually periodic?

Comment: @ETHproductions Everything in one group has to output the same thing

Comment: What if we get pi (or **phi**) as our argument???

Comment: @EriktheGolfer You don't. You get two integers.

Comment: @OliverNi I mean, like a super-approximate fraction, such as `22/7` for `π`. Can we assume that it's terminating or eventually periodic?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer What? Every fraction is either terminating or periodic. 22/7 is purely periodic.

Comment: @OliverNi Oh, right. My fault :P

Comment: 1/13=0.076923076923... In Your definition "A decimal is eventually periodic if it has an infinite number of decimal digits and has a finite number of decimal digits before its repetent (the part of the decimal that repeats.) " would be "eventually periodic" not purery periodic has you show in the test cases...

Comment: No, 1/13 is purely periodic because the repetent is '076923'. The 0 repeats with the repetent.

Comment: @OliverNi FYI, your hyperlink in the bounty was backwards. It should be \[Text Description\](URL), in case you didn't know why it didn't work.

Comment: That's what i did. It doesn't format in bounties...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
:gÆfḍ⁵ṢQ¬Ḅ
```

Accepts denominator and numerator (in that order) as arguments. Returns **0** for terminating, **1** for purely periodic, and **2** for eventually periodic. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=OmfDhmbhuI3igbXhuaJRwqzhuIQ&input=&args=MTE+NA) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=OmfDhmbhuI3igbXhuaJRwqzhuIQKw6ci4oG8xpM&input=MCwwLDAsMCwxLDEsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwyLDEsMCwxLDIsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMCwyLDIsMCwxLDIsMCwyLDEsMCwyLDIsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwwLDIsMSwyLDEsMiwxLDAsMSwyLDEsMiwxLDIsMCwyLDIsMCwyLDEsMCwyLDIsMCwxLDIsMCwyLDIsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMCwyLDEsMiwxLDIsMSwyLDEsMCwxLDIsMSwyLDEsMiwxLDIsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMSwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDA&args=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).

#### How it works

```
:gÆfḍ⁵ṢQ¬Ḅ  Main link. Arguments: d (denominator), n (numerator)

 g          Compute the GCD of d and n.
:           Divide d by the GCD, yielding the denominator of the simplified form.
  Æf        Yield all prime factors of the previous result.
    ḍ⁵      Test 10 for divisibility by each prime factor.
            This yields 1 for 2 and 5, 0 for all other primes.
      Ṣ     Sort the resulting Booleans.
       Q    Unique; deduplicate the sorted Booleans.
        ¬   Logical NOT; replace 0 with 1 and vice versa to yield one of the
            following arrays.
              [    ]  <- no prime factors (denominator 1)
              [   0]  <- only 2 and 5
              [1   ]  <- neither 2 nor 5
              [1, 0]  <- mixed
         Ḅ  Unbinary; convert from base 2 to integer.
            This maps [] and [0] to 0, [1] to 1, and [1, 0] to 2.
```

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>70</s> .. <s>68</s> 53 bytes

```
f=(a,b,s=[],x)=>a?(s[a]^=a)?f(a*10%b,b,s,x||a):x==a:0
```

Returns **0** for terminating, **true** for purely periodic and **false** for eventually periodic.

#### How it works

What we're doing here is actually simulating a division by hand:

1. `a?...:0` - If the numerator is zero, we stop here and return `0`. The sequence is *terminating*.
2. `(s[a]^=a)?...:x==a` - If we've already encountered this numerator before, it means that the sequence is periodic and is going to repeat forever. We stop here and return either `true` if `a` is equal to the first value `x` of the sequence (*purely periodic*) or `false` if it's not (*eventually periodic*).
3. `f(a*10%b,b,s,x||a)` - Else, we multiply the numerator `a` by 10. We compute the remainder of the division by the denominator `b`. And we repeat the process by using this remainder as the new numerator. (We also pass `a` as the first value of the sequence if it's not already stored in `x`.)

#### Example

- **Blue**: numerator = 1
- **Green**: denominator = 7
- **Red**: multiplications by 10
- **Black**: remainders
- **Gray**: quotient digits (we don't really care about them here, and the above code is not computing them at all)

[image: division]

Answer (score 9):

## Python, <s>62</s> <s>61</s> 59 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,d,r=[0,0]:(r[:3]+r).count(n)or f(10*n%d,d,r+[n])
```

Prints **1** for eventually periodic, **2** for purely periodic, and **4** for terminating.

Verify all test cases on [repl.it](https://repl.it/Dt9c/3).

Comment: Fascinating! What does `*r` do?

Comment: It unpacks the tuple **r**. `f(1, *(2, 3), 4)` is equivalent to `f(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Comment: So this would be 56 bytes in JS: `f=(n,d,...r)=>n in r?~(n>0?n==r[0]:2):f(10*n%d,d,...r,n)`

Comment: My bad, 63 bytes (I forgot that `in` serves a very different purpose in JS than in Python): `f=(n,d,...r)=>~r.indexOf(r)?~(n>0?n==r[0]:2):f(10*n%d,d,...r,n)`

Comment: @ETHproductions Neat. I guess `f=(n,d,...r)=>~(i=r.indexOf(n))?n&&!i:f(10*n%d,d,...r,n)` would work as well.

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, <s>49</s> <s>46</s> 45 bytes

Includes +3 for `-p`

Based on [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)'s elegant idea but implemented in a perlish way

Give input numbers on STDIN

```
terminating.pl <<< "2 26"
```

`termninating.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
/ /;1until$a{$_=$_*10%$' or$`}++;$_=$a{$`}
```

Prints a 2 if terminating. 1 if periodic and nothing if eventually periodic

Comment: All of the numbers in a certain group have to give the same value.

Comment: @OliverNi They do now

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>91</s> <s>88</s> <s>85</s> <s>79</s> <s>75</s> <s>74</s> 78 bytes

```
f=(n,d,g=(a,b)=>b?g(b,a%b):a,t=g(d/=c=g(n,d),10))=>n*~-d?t-1?f(n/c,d/t)/0:1:+f
```

Outputs `NaN` for terminating, `1` for purely periodic, and `Infinity` for eventually periodic.

#### Test snippet

```js
f=(n,d,g=(a,b)=>b?g(b,a%b):a,t=g(d/=c=g(n,d),10))=>n*~-d?t-1?f(n/c,d/t)/0:1:+f

l=(n,d)=>console.log(n+"/"+d+":",f(n,d))

for(i=1;i<10;i++)for(j=0;j<i;j++)l(j,i);
```

### Explanation

First, we divide both **n** and **d** by **gcd(d,n)**, to reduce the fraction to its simplest form. This lets us avoid situations like **2/6** where the result would otherwise be calculated as purely periodic. We also define variable **t** as **gcd(d,10)**; this will be used later.

The first check is whether **n** is **0** or **d** is **1**. If **n*(d-1)** is 0, we return `+f`, or **NaN**: the fraction is **terminating**.

The next check is whether **t** is **1**. If so, we return **1**: the fraction is **purely periodic**.

If **t** is *not* **1**, we divide **d** by **t**, run the whole function again, and divide by 0. If **n/(d/t)** is terminating, this returns **NaN/0 = NaN**: the fraction is **terminating**. Otherwise, it returns **1/0 = Infinity**: the fraction is **eventually periodic**.

Comment: Where is the reduction to the simplest form ?

Comment: @TonHospel Fixed.

Comment: @Arnauld I'm not sure what you mean. It returns `Infinity` for all of those values.

Comment: @Arnauld Aw, man, I thought I could get away with never adjusting `n`... Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 247 bytes

```
@set/af=%1,g=%2
:g
@if not %f%==0 set/ah=g,g=f,f=h%%g&goto g
@set/ae=d=%2/g
:l
@set/ag=-~!(d%%2)*(!(d%%5)*4+1)
@if not %g%==1 set/ad/=g&goto l
@if %d%==1 (echo Terminating)else if %d%==%e% (echo Purely Periodic)else echo Eventually Periodic
```

Uses my fast gcd10 trick from [Fraction to exact decimal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89215/fraction-to-exact-decimal). Obviously I could save a bunch of bytes by using a custom output format.

Comment: Why don't you just do `@if %d%==1 (echo T)else if %d%==%e% (echo P)else echo E` to save 42 bytes?

Comment: *Obviously I could save a bunch of bytes by using a custom output format.*

Comment: @ETHproductions I think he doesn't want to, as Oliver has noted with a quote.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 41 bytes

```
Ordering@{d=Denominator@#,GCD[d,10^d],1}&
```

Outputs `{3,1,2}` if the input has a terminating decimal expansion, `{2,3,1}` if the input has a purely periodic decimal expansion, and `{3,2,1}` if the input has an eventually periodic decimal expansion.

Based on the sneaky trick: if `d` is the denominator of a fraction in lowest terms, then the greatest common divisor of `d` and `10^d` equals `d` if `d` has only 2s and 5s in its prime factorization; equals `1` if `d` has neither 2s nor 5s in its prime factorization; and equals some integer in between if `d` has 2s/5s and other primes.

The `Ordering` function just reports where the smallest, next smallest, and largest elements of the triple are, with ties broken left-to-right.

Flaw: returns the variant output `{1,2,3}` instead of `{3,1,2}` if the input is 0.

## Mathematica, 46 bytes, perverse

```
b[a][[Log[d=Denominator@#,GCD[d,10^d]]]][[1]]&
```

Returns `a[[1]]` if the input has a terminating decimal expansion, `b[[1]]` if the input has a purely periodic decimal expansion, and `b[a]` if the input has an eventually periodic decimal expansion. Throws an error in all cases!

As above, we want to know whether that greatest common divisor equals 1, d, or somewhere in between. The base-d logarithm of that gcd equals 0, 1, or something in between.

Now we start torturing Mathematica. `b[a][[n]]` denotes the `n`th part of the expression `b[a]`. So `b[a][[1]]` returns `a`; `b[a][[0]]` returns `b`; and `b[a][[x]]`, where `x` is a number between 0 and 1, makes Mathematica throw the error "Part::pkspec1: The expression `x` cannot be used as a part specification." and returns `b[a][[x]]` unevaluated.

This already distinguishes the three cases appropriately, except that the output for the eventually periodic case is `b[a][[x]]`, which is non-constant because `x` is the actual logarithm of something. So then we apply `[[1]]` to the outputs already described. Because of how Mathematica internally represents `b[a][[x]]`, the result of `b[a][[x]][[1]]` is simply `b[a]`. On the other hand, applying `[[1]]` to `a` results in a different error "Part::partd: Part specification a[[1]] is longer than depth of object." and returns `a[[1]]` unevaluated (and similarly for `b`).

Flaw: lies about the input 0, returning `b[a]` instead of `a[[1]]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 15 bytes

This is based on [Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95934/47581). **0** is terminating, **1** is purely periodic, and **2** is eventually periodic. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4pa8Tnk5deKZgCVTUuKZgmLilZQyQMK_&input=WzEsMjBd)

```
▼Ny9u♀%SR♂b╔2@¿
```

**Ungolfing**

```
      Implicit input [a, b].
▼     Divide a and b by gcd(a,b).
Ny    Get the unique prime divisors of the reduced denominator.
9u    Push 10.
♀%    10 mod every member of uniq_p_d.
SR    Sort the mods and reverse.
♂b    Logical buffer. Converts every (10 % p != 0) to 1, and everything else to 0.
        Meaning if 2 or 5 divided b, they are now 0, and every other prime is now 1.
╔     Uniquify the list.
        If terminating, return [0].
        If purely periodic, return [1].
        If eventually periodic, return [1, 0].
        Else, (if b was 1), return [].
2@¿   Convert from binary to decimal. Return 0, 1, or 2.
      Implicit return.
```

Answer (score 2):

## C 173 Bytes

Takes two integers from stdin, prints 1 for purely periodic, -1 for eventually periodic, and 0 for terminating.

```
int r;main(_,n,d){_-1?_-2?d-1?d%2&&d%5?r=1:d%2?main(3,n,d/5):main(3,n,d/2),r=r?-1:0:r=0:d?main(2,d,n%d):r=n:scanf("%d %d",&n,&d),main(2,n,d),main(3,n/r,d/r),printf("%d",r);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
// returns 1 for periodic, 0 for terminating, <0 for eventually periodic
int periodic(int num, int den) { // 3
    if (den == 1) return 0;
    if (den % 2 && den % 5) // pure periodic
        return 1;
    if (den % 2) return periodic(num,den/5) ? -1 : 0;
    return periodic(num,den/2) ? -1 : 0;
}

int gcd(int num, int den) { // 2
    if (den) 
        return gcd(den,num%den);
    return num;
}

int main(n,d) // 1
{
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&d);
    printf("%d",periodic(n/gcd(n,d),d/gcd(n,d)));
    return 0;
}
```

Half-golfed:

```
int r;main(_,n,d){
    _-1? 
    _-2?
    // periodic
    d-1?
        d%2&&d%5?
            r=1:
                d%2?
                    main(3,n,d/5): //periodic
                    main(3,n,d/2), //periodic
                        r=r?-1:0:
                r=0
    // gcd
    :d?main(2,d,n%d):r=n // gcd
    // main
    :scanf("%d %d",&n,&d),
     main(2,n,d), // gcd
     main(3,n/r,d/r), // periodic
     printf("%d",r);
}
```

Comment: [165 bytes](https://tio.run/##Tc3BCsIwDAbgV9kKLatN2azUQ4f0UcpoUHYwSPQmPnttp4KnJPD9f7K95FwKz9dlpSEBAeonn5Ldx2RdxDpROqVQ@hjqFjd3aG70Gjj83U7vJtv3HKaAH@cAgSQ2R@GeFzoPQmInUYAiUKjNl7W35lc1ci1jbW680mNLCGA9v0rx3fEN "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 126 Bytes

```
$d=$argv[2];$a[]=$n=$argv[1];while($n%$d&&!$t){$n*=10;$t=in_array($n%=$d,$a);$a[]=$n;}if($a[1]&&$t)$t+=$a[0]!=end($a);echo+$t;
```

Prints 0 for terminated and 1 for purely periodic
2 for eventually.
Let me explain if a numerator is twice in the array here starts the periodic session
if it is terminated the `echo end($a);` value is `0`
If you not trust me put `$t=count($a)>$d?2:0;` in the loop

To make it more clear please add
`print_r($a);` or `var_dump($a);` or `json_encode($a);` after the loop

you can see one numerator twice or a zero at the end of the array
if a numerator is twice count the items between the two items and you can get the length of the periodic 
and you can see the position by the first numerator where the periodic begins

So after that we can find the position and the length of the periodic sequence with `if($t){echo $p=array_search(end($a),$a);echo $l=count($a)-$p-1;}`

### Visualize the periodic

```
$d=$argv[2];
$a[]=$n=$argv[1]; #array numerator
$r[]=$n/$d^0; #array result of the division
$r[]=".";
while($n%$d&&!$t){
    $n*=10; 
    $n-=$d*$r[]=$n/$d^0;
    $t=in_array($n%=$d,$a); #stop if numerator is twice 
    $a[]=$n;
}
if($a[1]&&$t)$t+=$a[0]!=end($a); #periodic term starts directly?
if($t){
    echo $p=array_search(end($a),$a)."\n"; #output the beginning position of the periodic term
    echo $l=count($a)-$p-1; #output the length of the periodic term
    echo "\n";
    echo str_repeat(" ",2+$p).str_repeat("_",$l-1)."\n"; #visualize the periodic term
    #echo join(array_slice($r,0,1+$p)).join(array_slice($r,1+$p))."\n";# if you want only the periodic term 
    echo join($r); #result if the division
}
echo+$t; # 0 terminated 1+2 periodic 2 periodic start not directly
```

### Output visualize the periodic term

```
1/18
   _
0.05

1/12
    _
0.083

1/13
  ______
0.076923

1/14
   ______
0.0714285
```

An other way with 130 Bytes

```
$r=bcdiv(($z=$argv)[1],$z[2],400);for($p=2;$i++<200;)if(substr($r,2,$i)==substr($r,2+$i,$i))$p=1;echo strlen(rtrim($r,0))<50?0:$p;
```

Expanded Version

```
$r=bcdiv(($z=$argv)[1],$z[2],400); # 100 is the maximal denominator 
# we need a string length with the double value of the sum the length from 1 until the denominator
for($p=2;$i++<200;)if(substr($r,2,$i)==substr($r,2+$i,$i))$p=1;
# all results begin with 0. 
#take two substrings with the same length after that and comparize both. 
#if we found 2 same substrings we have a periodic which starts at the first decimal place
echo strlen(rtrim($r,0))<50?0:$p; 
# if we can trim the length of the result we have a terminated result
```

Comment: See also [Fraction to exact decimal](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89215/fraction-to-exact-decimal).

Comment: @Neil you mean I should modify the code to answer the other question?

Comment: Well, I was just thinking the other question doesn't have a PHP answer; perhaps you would like to provide one.

Comment: @RosLuP  For the example 3/53 this array will be create `[3,30,35,32,2,20,41,39,19,31,45,26,48,3]`

Comment: 3 / 103 =0.0291262135922330097087378640776699029126213592233009708 and so in the same period can appear the same digit (for example the digit 7 between 00...00 above ) But if the array you speak about is not the one of digit but the array of the {d=10*(d%b)} where the digit is d/c than I think it is ok there is only one value d_i to each period...

Comment: @RosLuP okay for your example 3 /103 3%103 gives 3 put this in the array now you multiple with 10. 30%103 gives 30 this is the next value in the array 300%103 gives 94 and so on which results in this output `[3,30,94,13,27,64,22,14,37,61,95,23,24,34,31,1,10,100,73,9,90,76,39,81,89,66,42,8,80,79,69,72,102,93,3]`

Comment: above i would write for a/b d=a, {d=10*(d%b)} and the digit is d/b; for the remain ok for me should be ok for the array of {d}... 3,30, etc... i remember that the period would be a divisor of 102=103-1=p-1 in this case, if b is composite and has one some prime p_i it would be a divisor of p_i-1 [but possibly remeber wrong etc]

Comment: @RosLuP the array for 1/647 is one of the worst cases. It contains 647 items. foreach denominator d the worst case that can exists is that the count of the items is d

Comment: @JörgHülsermann in http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F647 if one type 1/647 it result period 646 [646 is a divisor of 647-1 where 647 is a prime number]... yes the worst case i think; but for say the true number a/b with a and b > 100 it seems are out the range of this code golf question...

Comment: @Neil I have add an answer to the other question. Not forgotten. Mnay other things to do

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 44 bytes

```
If[ListQ@Last@#,Length@#==1]&@@RealDigits@#&
```

Returns `Null` for Terminating, `True` for purely periodic, and `False` for eventually periodic.

## Explanation

```
RealDigits
```

Find the decimal expansion of N. (repeated digits are surrounded by an extra head `List {}`).

```
ListQ@Last@#
```

Check whether the last element of the decimal expansion is a `List`.

```
Length@#==1
```

If the above condition is `True`, check whether the entire decimal expansion consists of one thing. (A `List` counts as one entity). (returns `True` or `False`)

(If the condition is `False`, then a `Null` is returned because there is no third argument for `If`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>31</s> 27 bytes

```
AQ={P/HiGH?l@H=j25T?l-HT1Z2
```

Input

```
4,12
```

You can try it [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=AQ%3D%7BP%2FHiGH%3Fl%40H%3Dj25T%3Fl-HT1Z2&input=4%2C12&debug=0). Prints **1** for eventually periodic, **2** for purely periodic, and **0** for terminating. This is my first time answering in codegolf. Any suggestions are welcome.

### Explanation

```
AQ                                              // 1st element to G and 2nd element to H
    ={P                                         // Assign unique prime factors to H
        /H                                      // Simplify denominator
            iGH                                 // Find GCD
                ?l                              // Check length of filtered H
                    @H                          // Filter H by Y
                        =j25T                   // Assign a set [2,5] to T
                                ?l-HT           // Check length of H - T
                                        1Z2     // Print result
```

Note that [2,3] filtered by [2,5] = [2] but [2,3,5] - [2,5] = [3].

Answer (score 1):

### PARI/GP, 64 bytes

```
f(x,y)=if(setminus(factor(y=y/gcd(x,y))[,1]~,[2,5]),gcd(y,10)>1)
```

Outputs nothing for terminating, 0 for purely and 1 for eventually periodic.

Not very fancy, I hoped for something better when I started.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>16</s> 11 bytes

Saved 5 bytes thanks to @Adnan!

```
¿²r/fTrÖbÙJ
```

Prints 0 for Purely Periodic, 1 for Terminating, and 10 for Eventually Periodic.

Explanation:

```
                 # Implicit input
                 # Implicit input
  ¿              # Take GCD of numbers
   ²             # Push top value from input register
    r            # Reverse stack order
     /           # Divide (denominator by GCD)
      f          # Find unique prime factors
       TrÖ       # Test 10 for divisibility
          b      # Convert (True -> 1, False -> 0)
           Ù     # Deduplicate array
            J    # Join chars in array
                 # Implicit print
```

Input is taken as *p* newline *q*.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wr_CsnIvZlRyw5Ziw5lK&input=MQoz)

Comment: Nice to see you using 05AB1E :). Osabie also uses implicit input which allows us to remove the first two `I`'s. Furthermore, a constant predefined to `10` is `T`. Same for `2B`, which is `b` :).

Comment: You can also use the input registers, which gives us `¿²r/fTrÖbÙJ` as the final code :).