# Repetend length in 1/n

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, rational-numbers

This problem is based on non-terminating, repeating decimal points.

Let \$n\$ be any positive integer \$(n > 1 \text{ and } n < 10000)\$, say \$7\$. Then, \$1/n = 1/7 = 0.142857142857142857...\$

We see a pattern like, `0. 142857 142857 142857 ...` 
In this, the `142857` part is always repeating, which has length of \$6\$. Or, if \$n = 11\$, then \$1/n = 1/11 = 0.0909090909090909...\$

Here the length of the pattern is `2`. So, here goes the problem!

## Task

Given a positive integer \$n\$, \$(n > 1 \text{ and } n < 10000)\$, find the length of pattern in \$1/n\$, if it's repeating. Otherwise, return *any non-positive integer* (e.g., cases: \$1/5, 1/94, 1/22\$).
**Note that,** the pattern should start just after the decimal point. Hint: \$1/22 = 0.04545454545454545454545\$.

### Sample I/O

- `5 -> -1`
- `13 -> 6`
- `21 -> 6`
- `27 -> 3`
- `33 -> 2`
- `37 -> 3`
- `94 -> -1`
- `22 -> -1`
- `69 -> 22`
- `197 -> 98`
- `65 -> -1`
- [\$1/9979\$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F9979)
- [\$1/9967\$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F9967)

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the fewest bytes will win!

Comment: What should the output for n=1 be? I'd suggest guaranteeing that n>1, since n=1 is somewhat of a special case.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18541/78410). If anyone wants to close as dupe of this one, I'm not opposed to it.

Comment: Just to check: "non-positive integer" means an integer that isn't positive, or anything except a positive integer?  So: can we output zero (not a positive integer) for non-repeating patterns?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen - yes, non repeating patterns have no period, or 0 length.

Comment: I've decided to close this as a dupe for now since it seems there wasn't any difference in the overall algorithm, just the specifics of dealing with the "special cases" that sometimes lead to minor differences.

Comment: i don't agrée it's notre a dupe. Code golf the aim is to write the shortest and there are different ways. Check the answers. The "special cases" make the différence.

Comment: What are the actual answers for the last two test cases?

Comment: @JoKing - I think it's `4688` and `9966` as mentioned in there.

Answer (score 14):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
R⁵*%i1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/oUeNWLdVMw/@H2x81rfn/31RHwdBYR8HIEIjNdRSMgWxjIG1pAuQb6SiYWQLlLYECZkCFlpbmliDSzBwA)

Basically compute `10**[1..n] % n` and get the 1-based index of `1`.

Comment: wait i feel dumb for not figuring out at least a suboptimal version of this approach lmao

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 39 bytes

Expects a BigInt. Returns \$0\$ if there's no repeating pattern.

```javascript
f=(n,k=1n)=>10n**(k%=n)%n-1n?f(n,-~k):k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddBBDoIwEAXQvafohqQlVpyCpWNSPQtBMFIyNWJcevXqgrqw6frl/z@ZqXt1S/@43Z@S/GUIYbScts4CCXuCPZUld4UlUZAEOo9fk28nji70nhY/D7vZX/nIGWMHEoJVFZOw@TeoV9MJKchTu1KdUB0LVUr5FDb5E5XKm8a4lswBxjk0aS77EsQ2djbamET1rxW1Dh8)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L.Δ°I%
```

Port of [*@Bubbler*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214160/52210), so make sure to upvote him!
-1 byte thanks to *@ovs*.

Outputs `-1` if it's non-repeating.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fR@/clEMbPFX//zcyAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@koPCobZKCkn3loZX/ffTOTTm04dA61f@1Ov@jTXUMjXWMDHWMzHWMjXWMzXUsTXSMjHTMLHUMLc11zEx1LC3NLYGEmXksAA) (times out for the final test case).

**Explanation:**

```python
L       # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 .Δ     # Find the first value in this list which is truthy for:
        # (results in -1 if none are found)
   °    #  Take 10 to the power the current integer
    I%  #  Modulo the input-integer
        #  (Note: Only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
        # (after which the result is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: [6 bytes with `.Δ`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fR@/clEMbPFX//zcyAgA)

Comment: @ovs Ah, smart. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://git.sr.ht/%7Engn/k), <s>16</s> <s>23</s> 19 bytes

```
{1+(x(x!10*)\10)?1}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJwNxDEOgCAQBMCeV6yVoA17J1zWxo9Y8wYS4991ihnnwz3PPBfWrdys5eKb0lgb6DDCAu7wgA6YoQtUoDdIob8eH/HTDcM=)

As suggested by @traws (returns INT_MIN+1 if there's no repeating pattern), adapted to work with longer patterns that would otherwise overflow 64-bit integers.

- `x(...)\10` set up a monadic-do-scan, run for `x` iterations and seeded with `10`
- `(x!10*)` multiply the current value by 10, modding by the original `x` input
- `(...)?1` get the index of the first `1` showing up in the result (returns `0N` if no `1` is present, i.e. if there is no repeating pattern)
- `1+` add one to that result; converts `0N` to `-9223372036854775807`

Comment: You could do `{1+(x!*\x#10)?1}` in ngn/k, where 0N+1 wraps around becoming negative.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
R⁵*’ḍ@¹TṂȧ@⁸g10¤’¬¤o-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/oUeNWrUcNMx/u6HU4tDPk4c6mE8sdHjXuSDc0OLQEKH5ozaEl@br/D7c/alrz/7@pjoKhsY6CkSEQm@soGAPZxkDa0gTIN9JRMLMEylsCBcyACi0tzS1BpJk5AA)

This is probably very suboptimal (edit yes it is, i don't know why i didn't think to combine the two checks together cuz that would've given Bubbler's algorithm which is pretty smart).

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
€1m%¹↑İ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT8AwP9odXNr/23igoH/4oKsMW0lwrnihpHEsOKBsP///1s1LDEzLDIxLDI3LDMzLDM3LDk0LDIyLDY5LDE5Nyw2NV0)

Same approach as [Bubbler's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214160/95126).

```
€1m%¹↑İ⁰
€1          # index of first '1' in 
  m         # list of results of applying 
   %¹       # MOD n 
     ↑      # to first n elements of 
      İ⁰    # series of powers of 10 (starting at 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p` `-Mbigint`), 31 bytes

```perl
$_=++$i<$_?9x$i*1%$_?redo:$i:-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzLDoIwEEX3/QpC6gZSSVsYOuBr5c5vIBqJmQSBAAuN8detUOvqnjtzZvp6aDJ7f3IqxyRYR0lSviyvtnHMacOrPT44RXI101Bfu4JTIaR9l7MRHo6B2AW8Cm22gJBM6gWAKekzX1Iz7eaKad8x9QdKeQB0hmISnYOGwf8rYu62KRgzF/gJCPDp@om6drTi3PRWnC50o3b6Ag)

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
~:x,{10\?x%1=},0+1=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v86qQqfa0CDGvkLV0LZWx0Db0Pb/f0NjAA)

```
~:x                   # Assign the input to x                  13
   ,                  # Make an array from 0 to x-1            [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]
    {        },       # Find all numbers that pass this test
     10\?x%           # (10^k)%x                               [1 10 9 12 3 4 1 10 9 12 3 4 1]
           1=         # Is it 1?                               [1  0 0  0 0 0 1  0 0  0 0 0 1]
                      # Only the index of the 1s are kept      [0 6 12]
               0+     # Append 0                               [0 6 12 0]
                 1=   # Get the second number                  6
```

If it doesn't repeat, the array will be `[0 0]` and `0` will be outputted.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>55</s> 52 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to the man himself [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!

```c
i;m;f(n){for(i=m=1;(m*=10)%n&&m%n-1;++i);m=m%n?i:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNb4QgEL37KyYmbsDF1I/aZktpD01/hXrYKLYcYDfiwdT42@2grumWDAPz3jzgUUdfdT3PimveEkPH9tIRJbRIONGhSGIamMNBByZK@PGoKNcCi3f1EvNpVqYHfVaGUG/0AIcDeml7W1RizBkkGYM0wfnMIMN9huvpEeuUwVM@8V0kh6use9k4XYzcEk685HiNrb/@PnchdEUFAka/HD7Tcjh94Mx9Bn/rzN8U6AmIu0aZRg4oi/m2fQWrfuSlJbcH0IcNCHeEAxp33RRWl7dHGzxpdbvQFb9jLbLuR@9Riehu9r/s2mFLS/yggegNMAe2ND4zzLKusELIajtt8qb5Fw)

Returns either the length of repeated pattern of \$\frac{1}{\space n \space}\$ or \$0\$ for no repeated pattern.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVBNb4QgEL37KyYmbsDF1I/aZktpD01/hXrYKLYcYDfiwdT42@2grumWDAPz3jzgUUdfdT3PimveEkPH9tIRJbRIONGhSGIamMNBByZK@PGoKNcCi3f1EvNpVqYHfVaGUG/0AIcDeml7W1RizBkkGYM0wfnMIMN9huvpEeuUwVM@8V0kh6use9k4XYzcEk685HiNrb/@PnchdEUFAka/HD7Tcjh94Mx9Bn/rzN8U6AmIu0aZRg4oi/m2fQWrfuSlJbcH0IcNCHeEAxp33RRWl7dHGzxpdbvQFb9jLbLuR@9Riehu9r/s2mFLS/yggegNMAe2ND4zzLKusELIajtt8qb5Fw) by starting with `m=1`.

Comment: @Arnauld Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:i*(10**i%n==1)or~(i<n and~f(n,i+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxDoAgEATA3ldcYwJIwcWOyGMwiF6iiyE2Nn4dmXru9zkK5tZyOOO1pkiwEtiLUeyMkREhsC71U7KAItKXVR8Ta91yqQQSUI3YN8WWnXPaD3RXwdNbr739)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>45</s> <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```
n_:>Lookup[Mod[10^#,n]->#&~Array~n,1,0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcTRCsIgGAbQVxkIo@Bbm9omf5DUfUH3YiGr0YhpiF1EtFe3zsWZXLrfJpfG3uVhm/1low8hPF5PcwxXw5szg7eVZuW8j9G9Zw@OxuZTHH0yrNILVq@GpS2Leld8WnAJwSEUpIRUoDWEQEfgpNC1IFL0r1Pf/AM)

Defined as a [delayed rule](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) that can be applied to any integer.

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b739Cgzrc0pySzIAcoUJJZlupflJJaVKesrxfvEB@va2eg9j@gKDOvJFpZ1y7NQTlWTUHfQaHaVMfQWMfIUMfIXMfYWMfYXMfSRMfISMfMUsfQ0lzHzFTH0tLcEkiYmdf@BwA)

Comment: Very nice, @att! I think your code deserves a separate answer that I can upvote.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 29 bytes

```
0&@@10~MultiplicativeOrder~#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b730DNwcHQoM63NKcksyAHKFiSWZbqX5SSWlSnrPY/oCgzryRaWdcuzUE5Vk1B30Gh2lTH0FjHyFDHyFzH2FjH2FzH0kTHyEjHzFLH0NJcx8xUx9LS3BJImJnX/gcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 68 bytes

```
.+[1379]$
_,$&*_,;
\d+
0
{`;
;_
\G_
10*
+`(_+,)\1
,$1
^_,.+;(_+)
$.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDsIgFIDh/T8HmrYQ0ge2hHCAHkL0YaKDi4Nx8/C03/h9X7/35yH9NGyte3uVmPLNoM6cJ3WF@rTM/FuhKHVTZJ6wbVDrxio4I9zVeVuOGTFeel@QSBBCIkZiIl8IgTUjObEuOw) Link includes faster test cases. Explanation:

```
.+[1379]$
_,$&*_,;
```

If the number is coprime to `10`, then create a work area with the values `p=1`, `n` and `k=0` (in unary).

```
\d+
0
```

But if it is not coprime to `10` then set the answer to `0` immediately.

```
{`
```

Repeat until the answer is found.

```
;
;_
```

Increment `k`.

```
\G_
10*
```

Multiply `p` by `10`.

```
+`(_+,)\1
,$1
```

Reduce `p` modulo `n`.

```
^_,.+;(_+)
$.1
```

If `p=1`, then set the answer to `k` converted to decimal, which allows the loop to exit.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
ＮθＩ⊕⌕﹪Ｘχ…¹θθ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDObG4RMMzL7koNTc1ryQ1RcMtMy9Fwzc/pTQnXyMgvxyo2NBARyEoMS89VcNQR6FQUxNE6CgYagKB9f//hpbm/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Basically a port of @Bubbler's answer, except that my range goes from `1` to `n-1`. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ              Take input as a number
        …       Exclusive range
         ¹      From literal `1`
          θ     To input number
      Ｘ         Vectorised raise to power
       χ        Predefined variable `10`
     ﹪          Vectorised reduce modulo
           θ    Input number
    ⌕           Find index of
            ¹   Literal `1`
   ⊕            Increment
  Ｉ             Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 91 bytes

```
@set/ap=1,k=0
:g
@set/ak=-~k%%%1,p=p*10%%%1
@if %k% neq 0 if %p% neq 1 goto g
@echo %k%
```

Explanation: Repeatedly increments the answer and multiplies the power by 10 until (modulo the input) the answer wraps around to zero or the power reduces to 1.