# Long period primes

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

A long period prime is a prime number \$p\$ such that decimal expansion of \$1/p\$ has period of length \$(p-1)\$. Your task is to output this number sequence. For purposes of this challenge we will consider only odd primes.

[Period of a decimal expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal) of a rational number is the smallest period \$k\$ that makes the decimal representation periodic (repeating at regular intervals \$k\$).

This is [A001913](https://oeis.org/A001913), or [A006883](https://oeis.org/A006883) without leading \$2\$.

### Examples

\$\frac{1}{3}=0.33333\ldots\$, so the period is \$1\$ (although the number is also 2-periodic, 3-periodic etc., but we take the minimum). \$3-1=2\neq1\$, so \$3\$ won't appear in our sequence.

\$\frac{1}{7}=0.14285714\ldots\$ - the period is \$6 = 7-1\$.

### Rules

This is a standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)[sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenge, so please comply with the defaults.

With floating point errors, let's stick to the highest voted decisive answer [here on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20528/what-is-our-consensus-on-floating-point-issues/20529#20529), so I'll allow them.

### Test cases

First 10 entries:

```
7, 17, 19, 23, 29, 47, 59, 61, 97, 109
```

For more visit: [A001913's b-file](https://oeis.org/A001913/b001913.txt).

---

*Inspired by recent [Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmfxIhmGPP4).*

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18541/period-of-the-decimal-representation

Comment: IMO, allowing floating point errors makes the challenge uninteresting.

Answer (score 7):

## x86-64 machine code, 27 bytes

```
31 F6 FF C6 89 F1 6A 0A 58 99 F7 FE 6B C2 0A FF CA E0 F6 E2 ED FF CF 75 E9 96 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLLTsMwEDzHX7EEVdh9qQXEgVIuPXPhhEQ5uLaTGDl2yKO4VP11wjpphMCHjXdmd3bsWBTFLBWibS@1FaaRCh6qWmo3zx7JH8jo3X@s1DYNGFG@VqWFeBPDUdsaEhoiZ6sT4VUOFJ5jSuapcTtuICHJPYm8K0FVehoCsSiQI4jaXR7lbg9K@J6NiqbKYLnAjSug5J4YrBXyAxuk3vc1Om8MKB5aJIZQLZUICYmMc4X9AtPvoJs20Nj6jtwZ8yJLz7ZwTFSqmrAY2IqQcKCca9ufrEzFFETGSxiPMdkzciSAK5Ae1rCYwiF8Vh36mWmjgE4mHh7WsLxjHRpWgVdYJzQeaZg9wkhvbTwFtJ9Qz1jfPJRs7RMXmbYKhJPqPj7T/neMdHAcqmG0uH5BrcOa0sZWOrVKdobHLGGvfjJ5w58zGDvABYr4zc2/kUDR1@5Qq4r1xga@qYMUvdraqzOEN9XgC0AnJ9K23yIxPK3aWX53iwHfwBoVlfkB)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes a number \$n\$ in EDI and returns the 1-indexed \$n\$th long-period prime in EAX.

In assembly:

```
f:
    xor esi, esi        # Set ESI to 0.
nextm:
    inc esi             # Add 1 to ESI to get the next number (m) to test.
    mov ecx, esi        # Set ECX to m.
    push 10             # Push 10 onto the stack
    pop rax             #  and pop it into RAX.
l:
    cdq                 # Sign-extend, setting up for the next instruction.
    idiv esi            # Divide by m, putting the quotient in EAX and the remainder in EDX.
    imul eax, edx, 10   # Set EAX to EDX×10.
    dec edx             # Subtract 1 from EDX.
    loopnz l            # Subtract 1 from ECX, and repeat if both are nonzero.
    loop nextm          # Subtract 1 from ECX, and jump if the result is nonzero.
                        #   This point will be reached iff 1 is first obtained
                        #   after exactly m-1 iterations of ×10 and mod m.
    dec edi             # Subtract 1 from EDI, counting down from n.
    jnz nextm           # Jump if it is nonzero.
    xchg esi, eax       # Exchange the final value of m from ESI into EAX.
    ret                 # Return.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>73</s> 64 bytes

<s>The usual Wilson's theorem based prime generation combined with computing the multiplicative order.</s> Now porting [tsh's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244256/64121), you don't actually need to check for primality if the multiplicative order is right.

```python
k=3
while j:=1:
 while 10**j%k>1<k>j:j+=1
 j==k-1==print(k);k+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9vWmKs8IzMnVSHLytbQiksBwjE00NLKUs22M7TJtsuyytK2NeRSyLK1zdY1tLUtKMrMK9HI1rTOBgr//w8A)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript + `alert`, 57 bytes

```javascript
for(i=2n;++i;j-i||alert(i))for(j=1n;j<=i&10n**j++%i!=1;);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvBDoIwDIDhV6kHZaPBOK@lvssCw7RZVjMIJ959itf/z6dxj@tU5bMNxebUYk51A4Y9ZuAXTFZWy@me7e3OhNB1ntpi1Qk/CyEK6SDH8XdOvD@XciikI8stPErfK@JVLhzoJ9sX)

Comment: It seems to work for `i>1` too, I think the case `i==0` can never happen.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
tfλ=←⁰LUm%⁰İ⁰)N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/qG2iocGjpsb/JWnndts@apvwqHGDT2iuKpA6sgFIaPr9/w8A)

For each natural number (`N`), get the series of powers-of-10 (`İ⁰`) modulo that number (`m%⁰`); now select those (`fλ)`) for which the length (`L`) of the longest prefix of unique elements (`U`) is equal to (`=`) that number minus one (`←⁰`).  This annoyingly includes 2 at the start, so we need to take the tail (`t`).

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>12</s>  11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṖȯfƑ⁵*Ɱ%Ɗµ#
```

A full program that accepts an integer, `n`, from STDIN and prints the Jelly representation* of a list of the first `n` numbers which have a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) of \$10\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//4bmWyK9mxpHigbUq4rGuJcaKwrUj//82MA)**

<sup>* the Jelly representation of a list with a single element is just that element.</sup>

#### How?

```
ṖȯfƑ⁵*Ɱ%Ɗµ# - Main Link: no arguments
         µ# - implicitly takes input - call this N
         µ# - collect the first N values of K (in [0,1,2,...]) for which:
Ṗ           -   pop -> [1,2,...,K-1]
 ȯ          -   logical OR with K (so we get K when K is 0 or 1, rather than [])
                (let's call this list of integers (or 0 or 1) P)
        Ɗ   -   last three links as a monad - f(K):
    ⁵       -     10
      Ɱ     -     map across (implicit [1,2,...,K]) with:
     *      -       exponentiation
       %    -     modulo K (vectorises)
                (let's call this list of integers M)
   Ƒ        -   is P invariant under?:
  f         -     P filter keep M
            - implicit print
```

---

A couple of other 11 byters:

```
⁵*Ɱ%i1=ṖṪµ#
⁵*Ɱ%=1Ḅ⁼2µ#
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
Þp'ɾ↵$%1ḟ⇧=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnnAnyb7ihrUkJTHhuJ/ih6c9IiwiIiwiMTciXQ==)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's answer.

```
Þp'         # Filter the infinite list of primes by...
   ɾ        # 1...n
    ↵       # 10 to the power of each of those
     $%     # Modulo n
       1ḟ   # Find the first index of a 1
         ⇧= # Is it + 2 equal to n?
```

See, when I saw something about "powers of 10 modulo n" I thought it meant you could get something with an equivalent cycle in that way. I didn't realise it was so simple...

Comment: You've misspelled my first name. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen After *all* the effort I put into spelling your last name right...

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `lists.lazy math.primes.lists project-euler.026`, <s>57</s> 52 bytes

```
[ lprimes [ dup -1 ^ period-length - 1 = ] lfilter ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxDoIwFEV3vuL@AA04OGicjYuLcSKYNOUhlUfblMeAP1@LrOfknF4b8TE9H7f79YQQ/YeMlLQwRVUdjmA7y6xYf1dMWgYVop0ogw3vcuf94oxY72aMFB3xn@Yfiay5cYJzUdRVasD7Ag26JaCs8UKgaH1XMrl3jkrUuKAF95aFItpkNDNY9Ei5UpsibYb0Aw)

Believe it or not, Factor includes solutions to the first 200 or so Project Euler problems and exposes them the same way as any other vocabulary. Many of these vocabularies provide useful words, such as `project-euler.026` which provides the `period-length` word.

### Explanation

It's a quotation that outputs the infinite lazy sequence of long period primes.

- `lprimes` An infinite lazy list of primes.
- `[ ... ] lfilter` Select only those whose...
- `dup -1 ^ period-length - 1 =` ...reciprocals have a period length one less.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞ʒ©L.Δ°®%}®α
```

Port of [*@tsh*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244256/52210), and also outputs the infinite sequence.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9vc2FiaWX//@KInsqSwqlMLs6UwrDCriV9wq7Osf//)

**Explanation:**

```python
∞          # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 ʒ         # Filter it by:
  ©        #  Store the current value in variable `®` (without popping)
   L       #  Pop and push a list in the range [1,®]
    .Δ     #  Find the first value in this list which is truthy for:
      °    #   Push 10 to the power the value
       ®%  #   Modulo-`®`
           #   (Note: only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
     }     #  After we've found our result (or not, resulting in -1)
      ®α   #  Take the absolute difference with `®`
           #  (and again, only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
           # (after which the infinite list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 47 bytes

```ruby
7.step{|x|x-1==(1..x).find{|c|10**c%x<2}&&p(x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31yvuCS1oLqmoqZC19DWVsNQT69CUy8tMy@luia5xtBASytZtcLGqFZNrUCjQrP2/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```r
repeat if(T==match(1,10^(1:(T=T+1))%%T,0))cat(T,"")
```

[Try it at rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=%23%20here%20we%20use%20%27while(T%3C25)%27%20instead%20of%20%27repeat%27%20to%20output%20just%20long-period%20primes%20that%20are%20%3C25%3A%0A%0Awhile(T%3C25)%20if(T%3D%3Dmatch(1%2C10%5E(1%3A(T%3DT%2B1))%25%25T%2C0))cat(T%2C%22%22)) (but see below...)

Similar approach to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244265/95126): for each integer `T`, check whether the first `1` in the list of powers-of-10 modulo `T` occurs at the `T-1`-th position (meaning that the period of the decimal expansion is `T-1`).

Unfortunately, this approach suffers (quite badly) from inaccuracies as soon as the powers-of-10 exceed [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s floating-point precision: so, it only manages to output `7 17 19 23` before generating a large number of `probable complete loss of accuracy in modulus` warnings.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 65 bytes

```r
repeat{y=T=T+1;z=1;while(y&(z=(z*10)%%T)-1)y=y-1;cat(T[y==2],"")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxpLrSNsQ2RNvQusrW0Lo8IzMnVaNSTaPKVqNKy9BAU1U1RFPXULPStlLX0Do5sUQjJLrS1tYoVkdJSbP2/38A)

Alternative approach unaffected by floating-point inaccuracies (at least until very large values...); outputs a whitespace-separated list of all long-period-primes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 52 bytes

```
If[10~MultiplicativeOrder~k==k-1,Print@k]~Do~{k,∞}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zMt2tCgzrc0pySzIAcoVpJZlupflJJaVJdta5uta6gTUJSZV@KQHVvnkl9Xna3zqGNe7X@wmIJD@v//AA)

-15 bytes from @ovs

Comment: I'm not any Mathematica expert, but won't the example codes presented on the OEIS site result in shorter solution (using `MultiplicativeOrder` or `PrimitiveRoot` built-ins)?

Comment: @pajonk PrimitiveRoot does not work for 7 ... so you loose many bytes

Comment: I think `If[10~MultiplicativeOrder~k==k-1,Print@k]~Do~{k,∞}` should work for printing the sequence indefinitely. If you want to keep your IO format, the `MultiplicativeOrder` part still works for 63 bytes.

Comment: @ovs thanks, great!

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript + `alert`, <strike>54</strike> 53 bytes

```js
for(n=3;i=n++;i||alert(n))for(x=1;i*(x=x*10%n)>i--;);
```

Comment: Nice! I think you can save another byte with `x*=`

Comment: This seems to start with 2 when I click the 'run code snippet' button, but the sequence is supposed to start with 7...  Maybe it should start with ```for(n=3;...```?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Fair enough - updated

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>73</s> <s>72</s></sup> 71 bytes

```c
k,j,i;f(n){for(j=k=2;n-=j==k++-1;)for(i=10,j=0;j++<k&i%k>1;)i*=10;--k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHRUsIwEHz3K26YQVuaDLSoDIbw4vgVwkNpL5C2pkwTFGX4deuFAmomSZO9273bNOPrLGur2qxhOAS30RZoqroBh9ZpgmtTfQLnsK4rhTm8Y2N1bWBn0UKOKt1VDrRxsNo5yFLT5W9Sk1cIKohD4HOYtCUrmBYqMOGBxINCljIRhstCyjKKeCxCD2sZj1ghR6KIoll5q/vlnCJ6QLDgvBTH1ld6S7UJQjjcAA0P4H6LmcP8dQkSDhMGsV/To/CeHu9hpbsWqb07d@nNbdDiEyRjBsmUwT1RHuj7GDOYevqI@KcKWW0scTdpM6AdsxKbrlBvsX9JFvvpM62HHoO/93HvzPZPGfji2uS4J9pInI8zsPoLaxVc2g@HZ2BwRQRE0Sk7PIl1li@2Hal1UhHE4l/IUkgFLvyPIqHXtzoxl78J24ZSVNDr5/6P0d63C0OuHAPLrsZRSrs8yx5vju13pqp0bVv@8QM)

Returns the \$1\$-based \$n^\text{th}\$ long period prime.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
≔¹θＦＮ«≦⊕θＷ›⊖θ⊕⌕﹪Ｘχ…¹θθ¹≦⊕θ⟦Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY4xC8IwEIXn9lfceIEIzewkitKhUlzFIbZnG0iTNk3tIP72GKmIk2@44fg@3qta6SordQibcVSNQcFhYOv0Zh1gbvrJH6fuSg4Zg0eaFLL/cLmpHHVkPNWLkcyt0gR4cCR9FHb0BXBgHH4E3CtTY2HrSVss7RxpkXE4SdPQMoC9DwfBYuBfaemU8XjeytHHlkt8PUMQWVjd9Qs) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` long period primes. Explanation: Based on @tsh's answer.

```
≔¹θ
```

Start at `2` (because we increment this almost immediately). (Any number below `7` would work.)

```
ＦＮ«
```

Loop `n` times.

```
≦⊕θ
```

Increment the number under test.

```
Ｗ›⊖θ⊕⌕﹪Ｘχ…¹θθ¹
```

While the number's period is not equal to one less than it...

```
≦⊕θ
```

... increment the number under test.

```
⟦Ｉθ
```

Output the next long period prime.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 54 bytes

```
for ((;++n;))(r=9;for ((;r%n;))r+=9
((n+~$#r))||<<<$n)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY3zdLyixQ0NKy1tfOsNTU1imwtraEiRaogkSJtW0suDY087ToV5SJNzZoaGxsblTxNiG6oITDDAA)

Uses the fact that the repeating decimal period of \$ n \$ is the minimum integer \$ i \$ such that \$ n \$ divides \$ r = 10^i - 1 = \operatorname{rep}(9, i)\$.

Prints the sequence infinitely, but can only manage the first 3 terms before Zsh's floating point numbers implode.

We have to be careful with how and where we use `$r` to ensure it stays a string, so that `r+=9` literally appends instead of adds 9.

Answer (score 1):

## [Sidef](https://github.com/trizen/sidef), 39 bytes

```
{10.is_primitive_root(_)&&.say}<<2..Inf
```